# How to get values from another SP and insert it into the temporary table in one SP in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure1` ()
BEGIN
create temporary table temp;
insert into temp (call procedure2(param1,param2,param3));
END




CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure2` (param1,param2,param3)
BEGIN
create temporary table temp1
with recursive cte (id, parent_id, node_level) as (select query using param1,param2,param3);
select * from temp1;
END
```

Above is the situation I am facing, Whether we have any way to insert another SP result into a temp table of main SP?

I have created a procedure2(store procedure) that will return a table. Then I have created a procedure1(store procedure) that execute the procedure2 inside itself and after executing procedure2 will return a Table with number of rows. I need to get the Table returned from the procedure2 and insert into Temporary table in procedure1.Whether I have any way for that?

Comment: The question looks oversimplified

Comment: @P.Salmon Please check this again bro

Comment: A select retrieves data it does not return a table nor is the result of a select in proc2 available in proc1. - The published proc2 code seems pointless since an insert..select in proc1 would do - which is why I thought the question oversimplified

Comment: SELECT performed in SP sends the output to the output stream. I.e. when SP finishes then the data is already in the output stream, and it cannot be retrieved back from there. So the rowset produced in stored procedure cannot be a rowsource in a query. Noway to perform the operation which you describe. Alter `procedure2`, save the rowset produced in it to temptable (i.e. use not single `SELECT` but `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE .. SELECT` or `SELECT .. INTO`) with some pre-defined name, then use this temptable in `procedure1`.

Comment: @P.Salmon now please this bro. I will do some operations in the proc2 according to the parameters passed from the proc1.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for the help, It supports in the MS SQL server and now I am migrating my SP's to MySQL and this why I had raised this question, Thank you

Comment: MySQL does not have table datatype, rather than SQL Server. So your construction cannot be migrated directly.

Comment: @Akina Hay friend, I got an answer for this I will post you in few minutes.

Comment: We'll wait. This can be interesting..

Comment: @Akina Answer has been posted friend if you have any doubts let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure1` ()
BEGIN
create temporary table temp(column1, column 2);
create temporary table temp1(column1, column 2);
WHILE (CONDITION) DO
call procedure2(param1,param2,param3);
insert into temp (select * from temp1);
TRUNCATE temp1;
END WHILE;
select * from temp;
drop table temp1;
drop table temp;
END




CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure2` (param1,param2,param3)
BEGIN
create temporary table temp2
with recursive cte (id, parent_id, node_level) as (select query using param1,param2,param3);
Insert into temp1(select * from temp2);
DROP TABLE temp2;
END
```

Here I need to execute a piece of code in while loop for that I had added to proc2. Before calling that proc2 in proc1 we need to create one temporary tables(temp) and since it is created before calling the table will remain for proc2. We need to insert the result table of proc2 into the temp and we can now access the table from proc1 after the execution of proc2 completed.

In my case it is a while loop, so I had created two temporary tables (temp,temp1) and I use temp1 as my temporary table to get data from proc2 and then insert into temp (select * from temp1) and then truncate the values of temp1 and the loop goes on till the condition fails and I get the result table temp and I can use data for the proc1

If you have any doubts let me know, thank you.

Comment: This is the method which I have described in the comment.

Comment: For to avoit the interference with another code which is executed in the same connection and which may use the same names for temptables I recommend you to use a prefix which is equal to stored procedure name. I.e. not `temp` but `procedure1_temp`. This guarantees that the table with this name will be created only in this procedure. Also always perform `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS` before the table creation.

Comment: You loose your temptables definitions - this code will fail with error message `'A table must have at least one visible column.'`.

Comment: @Akina yah you will get that error for that you need to specify coloum's that are needed to insert, i will change the answer now.

Comment: @Akina Thank you friend for your help, I didn't noticed you had said the answer before itself, I didn't understood what you had told me. Anyway, thank you so much.